# How to generate a random list of ints in Python3?

Tags: python, random, python-3.7

My idea is as follows:

```
l=[]
for i in range(10):
    l.append(random.randint(0,100))
```

But is there a more convenient way to generate a random list of ints since I've imported the random module?

Comment: my_list = [random.randint(0,100) for r in range(10)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is most "convenient", but [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns a list of specified length from a given population.

```
random.choices(range(100), k=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [random.randint(0,100) for r in range(10)]
```